# Get value from div.

Tags: php, forms, html, input

Is there a way to get the value from a div element within a form instead of using a input?

I know it's kinda a dumb question, but I just want to know if its possible. Something like PHP DOM?

Or is there a way to possible changing the div to an input when hitting submit?

Thanks,

Comment: Just for the sole purpose of learning. I want to see if its possible, and learn from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Javascript, you can put the div's content into a (hidden) input right before you submit the form.

It will approximately look like this in jQuery:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  $('#myHiddenInput').val($('#myDiv').html());
});
```

Edit: Why are you guys talking about AJAX? There's no need of using AJAX in this situation!

Comment: The inner `$('#myForm').submit();` is not necessary. The form will submit as long as the function doesn't return false or call `e.preventDefault()`.. As you have it this will recurse infinitely.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a JavaScript solution *without* [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<script>

    function prepareSubmit() {
        var payload = document.getElementById("target").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("divContents").value = payload;
        return true;
    }​

</script>
```

Markup:

```
<form name="test">
    <div id="target">Payload</div>
    <input type="hidden" id="divContents" name="divContents" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return prepareSubmit()" value="submit" />
</form>​
```

The onclick function runs before the submit event. In fact, the form won't submit unless `prepareSubmit` returns true. It inserts the `div` contents into a hidden input. I think this is the simplest solution. Make sure the script is loaded before the form.

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/xwckr/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put `prepareSubmit` in the `onsubmit` attribute of the form? That way, it would handle all types of submits, like pressing enter in a form element.

Answer (score 2):

PHP code is processed on the server-side, so there principally could be no PHP manipulation of the client-side DOM.

Using JavaScript (easiest imho with jQuery) you can pull information out of the DOM and include it in the form submission as additional fields.

There are a bunch of questions on SO that deal with adding to the form submission using jQuery, e.g.

[Safari / JQUery - Insert and Update Hidden Field On Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295470/safari-jquery-insert-and-update-hidden-field-on-page)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to post the information within the div. Very simple to do, only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an ajax call within a javascript file.  All you would need to do is call the div id for example like this $("#yourdiv").val();
This will give you the value of whatever is in the div id.
If you give a more specific example and show some of your code, I might be able to be more specific.
Jim

Comment: You can't use val() on a div, because it doesn't have a... value.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to archieve this.

**Hidden fields**

You can create hidden input fields and fill these with javascript on submit

**Ajax**

Use for example jQuery's  AJAX library to serialize the data and post it via AJAX

**Style input fields so they look like the div you're talking about**

Another option is to just use input fields as you're use to and style them in a way that they don't look like inputs anymore

Let me know if you need an example of any of these.