# Adding chunks of text to a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to add chunks of text to a MySQL database. The following is a snippet of my HTML code:

```
    <div class="margins3">
    <h1>Meal Plan...</h1>
    <div id='results-container'>
    <div class='LeanMuscle Vegetarian NonBackLoadDayCBL MinimalCooking'><b>Meal 1: Accelerator Shake</b><br>
    1/2 scoop whey protein, 2 tsps coffee, 2 tbsps coconut oil<br>
    10g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 30g fat = 310 calories<br>

    <b>Meal 2: Tofu Salad</b><br>
    1 can tofu, 1tbsp olive oil, handful of salad leaves<br>
    30g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 7g fat = 183 calories<br>

    <b>Meal 3: Quorn Broccoli</b><br>
    1 bag of Quorn cubes, broccoli florets<br>
    30g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 5g fat = 165 calories<br> 

    <b>Meal 4: Pre-workout Ignition Formula Shake</b><br>
    1/2 scoop whey protein, 2 tsps coffee, 2 tbsps coconut oil<br>
    10g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 30g fat = 310 calories<br> 

    <b>Meal 5: Post-workout Hypertrophic Potentiator Shake</b><br>
    2 scoops whey protein, 5ml creatine, 5g leucine, 1 ripe banana<br>
    40g protein, 25g carbohydrates, 0g fat = 260 calories <br>

    <b>Meal 6, 7, and/or 8: Non-Back-Load Meals</b><br>
    Anything consisting of meals 2 and 3. Other options include egg whites, soya, cottage cheese, or other cheeses.
</div>
<div class='FatLoss NoRequirements BackLoadDayCBL ModerateCooking'><b>Meal 1: Accelerator Shake</b><br>
    1/2 scoop whey protein, 2 tsps coffee, 2 tbsps coconut oil<br>
    10g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 30g fat = 310 calories<br>

    <b>Meal 2: Tuna Salad</b><br>
    1 can tuna, 1tbsp olive oil, handful of salad leaves<br>
    30g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 7g fat = 183 calories<br>

    <b>Meal 3: Chicken Broccoli</b><br>
    1 chicken breast, broccoli florets<br>
    30g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 5g fat = 165 calories<br> 

    <b>Meal 4: Pre-workout Ignition Formula Shake</b><br>
    1/2 scoop whey protein, 2 tsps coffee, 2 tbsps coconut oil<br>
    10g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 30g fat = 310 calories<br> 

    <b>Meal 5: Post-workout Hypertrophic Potentiator Shake</b><br>
    2 scoops whey protein, 5ml creatine, 5g leucine, 1 ripe banana<br>
    40g protein, 25g carbohydrates, 0g fat = 260 calories <br>

    <b>Meal 6, 7, and/or 8: Back-Load</b><br>
    Anything consisting of starchy and/or sugary carbohydrates (fast-digesting, high GI)
    No need to calorie count, but try to keep an eye out for the amount of carbs you are ingesting, just so you can tweak your meals based on your visible results
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The code may not make sense right-off-the-bat, but what's happening here is that my HTML page is generating a meal plan based on what options the user chooses in four drop-down lists. For example, if you look at the first meal plan, you'll see its div class is made of concatenated strings: **'LeanMuscle Vegetarian NonBackLoadDayCBL MinimalCooking'**. Each of these strings is an option from one of the four drop-down lists, and if this specific set of options is selected, then the following meal plan will be loaded onto the screen. This successfully works.

What I want to do now is to store a generated meal plan into the **members** table of my SQL database. I have given a **mealPlan** field in the **members** table, so I'd like that to contain the chosen meal plan if the user clicks a **save** button. The following is my PHP script that should generate should the user click the save button:

```
<?php

//define database

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','root');

//connect to the database

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

//function to save a meal plan

function SaveMealPlan()
{
$mealplan = $_POST['results-container']; //this is the class id that encapsulates all meal plans in the HTML file
$query = "INSERT INTO members (mealPlan) VALUES ('$mealplan')";
mysql_query($query);
echo "Successfully Added. Please press back on your browser.";
}

//if the user presses save, this script generates the SaveMealPlan() function

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
SaveMealPlan();
}
?>
```

Forgive me if you notice any rookie errors, I am fairly new to this. By my logic, this code should be the basis to do what I want, although I am unsure of one thing:

- Do I reference **'results-container'** in my PHP script? Unlike
  traditionally referencing a form name, I am referencing a **div id**, as
  there is no form. Is this viable? If this is not allowed, should I
  add **`<div name="mealPlan">`** at the top of the meal plans, and then reference
  the div name in my PHP script?
- If this does work, I only want the system to store the chosen meal
  plan. It looks to me that using 'results-container' would store **both** meal plans shown, which isn't good. I can't identify a way of only storing the chosen plan.
- Do I need **`<form method="POST" action="savemealplan.php">`** anywhere for my save button? I am sure I do (as I'm posting data out and redirecting to my PHP script), but I am not using a form, therefore I'm not too sure if this piece of code is relevant? Once again apologies for the rookie questions.

Apologies for the extensive post, this is one of the final steps to get my system working and I would really appreciate it if any of you could direct me towards the right path or provide a solution. It seems simple enough, but storing dynamically-generated text as opposed to values entered in a form has proven to be more of a difficult task.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: it would be better to use `ajax` and trigger it on `save button click` to pass the data from the html document to the php file, it would be easy and fast. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Unfortunately I am very unfamiliar with ajax and cannot see what I'm looking for. Would you be able to assist me on this or provide a solution using only HTML and PHP? Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I reference 'results-container' in my PHP script? Unlike traditionally referencing a form name, I am referencing a div id, as there is no form. Is this viable? If this is not allowed, should I add  at the top of the meal plans, and then reference the div name in my PHP script?

No, there is no way you can get access to a non-form element in a PHP script. A better way might to have a hidden input element and when the user clicks submit, have the JavaScript `onSubmit` handler change the contents of that hidden input the contents of the div. For example: [Get value from div.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856230/get-value-from-div)
Read @paislee's answer as I do not recommend the use of jQuery.

> If this does work, I only want the system to store the chosen meal plan. It looks to me that using 'results-container' would store both meal plans shown, which isn't good. I can't identify a way of only storing the chosen plan.

You can have an if statement to decide which option was selected by the user, for example, you have the following HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="handle.php">
    <select name="meal_plan">
         <option value="good_meal">Good Meal</option>
         <option value="very_good_meal">Very Good Meal</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Now, the PHP to decide what form was selected:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["meal_plan"] == "good_meal") {
        echo [The good meal div]  // you get this from doing a sql query
    } else {
        echo [The very good meal div]
    }
?>
```

> Do I need  anywhere for my save button? I am sure I do (as I'm posting data out and redirecting to my PHP script), but I am not using a form, therefore I'm not too sure if this piece of code is relevant? Once again apologies for the rookie questions.

Yes, you need to have your input button inside of the form like shown in the above HTML code.

*Sorry if I wasn't that much help.* You question seemed a bit vague to me and I was not able to comprehend it all that much, hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, however I don't think this does what I asked as I want to add the text that's generated from a series of drop-down lists to my database. This could work if I was only using one drop-down list. Nevertheless, your time is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of example and question that are based on `ajax` and that they are answered too, im just giving a swift based here for you to work on,

**Updated:**

**Your HTML + Javascript:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#saveButtonClick').on('click', function(){
            var dataToBeInserted = $('#meal1').text();
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: insertDataToDB.php,
                    data:{'dataToBePass': dataToBeInserted},
                    success:function(results){   
                        //alert is ssuccess
                        alert('data is successfully inserted');
                    }
            });
    });
});

</script>
<div class="margins3">
    <h1>Meal Plan...</h1>
    <div id='results-container'>
        <div id="meal1" class='LeanMuscle Vegetarian NonBackLoadDayCBL MinimalCooking'><b>Meal 1: Accelerator Shake</b><br>
            1/2 scoop whey protein, 2 tsps coffee, 2 tbsps coconut oil<br>
            10g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 30g fat = 310 calories<br>

            <b>Meal 2: Tofu Salad</b><br>
            1 can tofu, 1tbsp olive oil, handful of salad leaves<br>
            30g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 7g fat = 183 calories<br>

            <b>Meal 3: Quorn Broccoli</b><br>
            1 bag of Quorn cubes, broccoli florets<br>
            30g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 5g fat = 165 calories<br> 

            <b>Meal 4: Pre-workout Ignition Formula Shake</b><br>
            1/2 scoop whey protein, 2 tsps coffee, 2 tbsps coconut oil<br>
            10g protein, 0g carbohydrates, 30g fat = 310 calories<br> 

            <b>Meal 5: Post-workout Hypertrophic Potentiator Shake</b><br>
            2 scoops whey protein, 5ml creatine, 5g leucine, 1 ripe banana<br>
            40g protein, 25g carbohydrates, 0g fat = 260 calories <br>

            <b>Meal 6, 7, and/or 8: Non-Back-Load Meals</b><br>
            Anything consisting of meals 2 and 3. Other options include egg whites, soya, cottage cheese, or other cheeses.
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="save" id="saveButton">
    </div>
 </div>
```

and now your your ready to pass the `data` that is all the meals into your php file, and I'm using as php file name is `insertDataToDB.php`, using your code;

**PHP:**

```
<?php

//define database

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','root');

//connect to the database

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$mealplan = $_POST['dataToBePass']; //the data you've attain from ajax

//your query
$query = "INSERT INTO members (mealPlan) VALUES ('$mealplan')";
if(mysql_query($query)){
   echo "Successfully Added. Please press back on your browser.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. This is starting to make sense. One question though, what about the PHP part of the solution?

Comment: for that you need to use a hidden `input form` and still use a `javascript` or `jquery` to save those values/text in the hidden form so you can easily pass them into a php file. and if this help mark check :)

Comment: Apologies @rockStar, I'm still having no luck. Would you be able to walk me through each stage? I'm not sure what you mean by hidden form. And yes if this works for me I'll be sure to mark check!

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and let you know how I progress. Thanks so much for your time and support. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @rockStar. An issue I've noticed here is that the 'save' button will only save meal1. What about the other meals? I could add a button for each meal plan (and also ajax script but that could be tedious). Do you know a way as to how the save button could only save the meal plan that the use has selected? Many thanks

Comment: you can think of a way to make it dynamically, and if it where i would make a save button in each meal so i can control which meal to save and not and u just need a click listener for that, everything has been hand out already u need to think of a way to make it happen for you now. As answering all ur question wont help u out as u need to practice it for urself too.